# Is there anyway to connect to AWS RDS MySQL from svelte client?

Tags: amazon-rds, svelte

I understand that it is not desirable.
But I wanted to know if at all it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with SvelteKit, which is an application framework for Svelte.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938328/how-do-i-integrate-mysql-with-sveltekit-nodejs - seems like solution should work both in nodejs and browser - I wonder if that's what OP is looking for since they say "it is not desirable" - MySQL queries in browser would not be good in most cases - but maybe this is a special dev/test case.

Answer (score 0):

No - Svelte is a HTML/CSS/JS front-end Javascript framework used to create user interfaces, not connect to databases (wherever they may be).