# Data read from the db using the endpoint appears as undefined

Tags: mysql, svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

I used the second method found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799801 and applied it to my source.

`The version of sveltekit I am currently using is 1.0.0-next.73.`

However, when I printed the data to the console, I could only see `undefined`.

[image: chrome console message]

Below is my source code:

`/lib/db/mysql.js`

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

let mysqlconn = null;

export function mysqlconnFn() {
      if (!mysqlconn) {
            mysqlconn = mysql.createConnection({
                  host: 'localhost',
                  port: 3307,
                  user: 'dbuser',
                  password: 'dbpassword',
                  database: 'dbname'
            });
      }

      return mysqlconn;
}
```

`/routes/index.server.js`

```
import { mysqlconnFn } from '$lib/db/mysql';

export async function get() {
      let mysqlconn = await mysqlconnFn();

      let results = await mysqlconn.query('SELECT * FROM list_user')
            .then(function ([rows, fields]) {
                  // console.log(rows);
                  return rows;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                  console.log("err")
            })

      return { results }
}
```

/routes/index.svelte

```
<script>
      export let data
      import { onMount } from "svelte"

      onMount(() => {
            console.log(data)
      });
</script>
```

I'd be grateful if you could tell me where I went wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in [routes](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) *have to* be called:

- `+page.svelte`
- `+page.js`/`ts`
- `+page.server.js`/`ts`
- `+server.js`/`ts`

So not `index`, also if you want [data to load](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load), the function (in `+page.server.js`/`ts`) has to be called `load`.

Comment: Oh, the version I'm working on doesn't use filenames like that! Is there any way I can update to the latest version right now and make it work?

Comment: There is a [migration guide](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774) for the big routing change, try to follow that.